# # of records in table divided into pages - ASP.Net MVC Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I make the `HTML` `table` display 10 records only and whenever it goes beyond 10 it will display a link for pages below? e.g. "1, 2, 3.." And limits up to 7 links like how YouTube displays it (See image below)? I'm using ASP.Net MVC with Bootstrap by the way.

```
<table id="userTbl" onclick="getTblRec('userTbl,'userBody','0')" class="table-scroll table-striped bootgrid-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="hidden">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USR_ID)
            </th>
            <th class="hidden">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.USR_FNAME)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="userBody">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td id="userId" class="hidden">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USR_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.USR_FNAME)
                </td>
                <td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

YouTube sample pic:

[image]

Comment: How do I go about it? Should this be done in Javascript? Or css? Or mvc?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of implementing pagination, Server and Client side. Firstly server implementation, Load only the set of items that are to be shown for the page from the server along with the page options. Pagination at the client side, load the entire set of items and provide pagination with the support of table and/or other controls. Both the options have pros and cons. These links should get you started on the topic,[link1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) , [link2](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/10/30/ASPNET-MVC-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx).

Comment: So that's the term for that, pagination. Thanks for the link dude! I'm gonna check it in my free time :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using ASP.NET MVC, there is an build in helper named `WebGrid` for scenarios like paging. This is super easy to use and provides almost all the functionality that you may need.

You can also take a look at this beginner level walk through. 
[WebGrid in asp.net mvc (By Sheo Narayan)](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3139/webgrid-in-aspnet-mvc).

Answer (score 1):

Make a partial view for paging and call that partial view if records you have more than 10. i.e. in this link [Paging](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Or you can install this nuget also, and your wish style would be able to design this is link for nuget [Nuget Packege](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/)